# Requested Service Not Found Error After Changing Default Constructor in Config File

Tags: remoting, spring.net

I have developed Client and Server Applications using remoting in Spring Dot Net. I add following line in App.Config file of Server

```
<constructor-arg type="int" value="3"/>
```

I starts my Server. But when I Starts Client application , I am getting error as Requested Service Not Found.
If I removed above line, my code works. 
Can you please provide me solution to invoke parameterised constructor?
What changes shll I make in Client?

You can refer to http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/remoting-quickstart.html

Comment: The (working) remoting quickstart creates instances of `AdvancedCalculator`, which takes an integer as constructor parameter. So it is definitely possible to use a "parameterised constructor". Could you try to reproduce the error using the quickstart you refer to and post the config files you use for server and client?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. There is error in cs file.

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear. If you think your solution is helpful to others, you can answer your own question and accept your own answer. This way everybody here knows your problem was solved. See the [faq for details](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: The application that I am developing has lots of parameterised constructors and some basic initialization commands. Its console application. By mistake, in on of the parameterised constructor, I wrote Console.ReadLine().So some of my services not get invoked. At the same time client tries to access that service and getting error as requested service not found.